# Need help in using Mechanize module in Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am learning to parse the data using mechanize but I have got a problem in the script:

**Script 1**

```
import mechanize
myBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
myBrowser.open("http://realpython.com/practice/aphrodite.html")
print myBrowser.response().get_data()
```

**Script 2**

```
import mechanize
myBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
htmlPage = myBrowser.open("http://realpython.com/practice/aphrodite.html")
print htmlPage.get_data()
```

Now the difference in both the script is little. In first, myBrowser.open() is not assigned to a variable while in second it is assigned to a variable named htmlPage. Now the problem is, according to my knowledge you need to use response method and method of response like get_data to get the data of webpage. But in my second script I'm not using response method and directly using get_dat() method and if i use response in second script it gives error. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Using `htmlPage = myBrowser.open("http://realpython.com/practice/aphrodite.html")` is assigning the variable to  `mechanize.Browser().open()` which gives you access to only the `mechanize.Browser().open()` methods and attributes.

In the second example you are using `myBrowser = mechanize.Browser()` so you have access to all the `mechanize.Browser()` methods and attributes.

There is no `mechanize.Browser().open().resonse` method only a `mechanize.Browser().response`

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. Appreciate it!